Caesar Cipher NASM Program – Issues with File Handling and Character Shifting
I'm trying to implement a Caesar Cipher in NASM (32-bit) that reads from an input file, applies a shift, and writes to an output file. The program should shift each letter by the given amount and handle errors if files can't be opened.
Here's the code:
section .data
    usage db "Usage: ./caesar {input_file} {output_file} {shift}", 10, 0
    len_usage equ $ - usage  ; Calculate the length of the usage string
    
    error_open_in db "Error: Cannot open input file.", 10, 0
    len_error_open_in equ $ - error_open_in  ; Calculate the length of the error_open_in string
    
    error_open_out db "Error: Cannot open output file.", 10, 0
    len_error_open_out equ $ - error_open_out  ; Calculate the length of the error_open_out string
    
section .bss
    bytes_read resd 1
    bytes_written resd 1
    buffer resb 1024               ; Buffer for reading
    buffer_size equ 1024           ; Buffer size
    
section .text
    global _start
    
_start:
    ; Check the number of arguments
    mov eax, dword [esp+4]         ; argc
    cmp eax, 4                     ; argc should be 4
    je process_args
    
    ; Print the usage message
    mov eax, 4                     ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1                     ; stdout
    mov ecx, usage                 ; Address of the usage string
    mov edx, len_usage             ; Length of the usage string
    int 0x80                       ; Call kernel
    jmp exit
    
process_args:
    ; Get arguments
    mov ebx, dword [esp+8]         ; argv[1] (input_file)
    mov ecx, dword [esp+12]        ; argv[2] (output_file)
    mov edx, dword [esp+16]        ; argv[3] (shift)
    
    ; Open input file
    mov eax, 5                     ; sys_open
    mov edi, ebx                   ; input_file
    mov esi, 0                     ; O_RDONLY
    int 0x80
    cmp eax, 0                     ; Check for error
    jl error_open_input
    mov ebx, eax                   ; Save input file descriptor
    
    ; Open output file
    mov eax, 5                     ; sys_open
    mov edi, ecx                   ; output_file
    mov esi, 578                   ; O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC (0666)
    mov ebp, 0666                  ; File permissions
    int 0x80
    cmp eax, 0                     ; Check for error
    jl error_open_output
    mov ecx, eax                   ; Save output file descriptor
    
    ; Get shift
    mov eax, edx                   ; shift
    sub eax, '0'                   ; Convert ASCII to number
    mov edx, eax                   ; Save shift in edx
    
read_loop:
    ; Read from input file
    mov eax, 3                     ; sys_read
    mov ebx, ebx                   ; Input file descriptor
    mov ecx, buffer                ; Buffer for reading
    mov edx, buffer_size           ; Buffer size
    int 0x80
    cmp eax, 0                     ; EOF or error
    jle close_files
    mov dword [bytes_read], eax
    
    ; Process data
    mov esi, buffer                ; Pointer to buffer
    mov ecx, dword [bytes_read]    ; Number of bytes read
process_char:
    mov al, byte [esi]             ; Get character
    cmp al, 'A'                    ; Check if uppercase
    jb skip_char
    cmp al, 'Z'
    ja check_lower
    ; Uppercase processing
    sub al, 'A'
    mov ebx, 26                    ; Divisor for circular shift
    div bl                         ; Divide by 26
    add al, 'A'
    jmp store_char
check_lower:
    cmp al, 'a'
    jb skip_char
    cmp al, 'z'
    ja skip_char
    ; Lowercase processing
    sub al, 'a'
    mov ebx, 26                    ; Divisor for circular shift
    div bl                         ; Divide by 26
    add al, 'a'
store_char:
    mov byte [esi], al             ; Save character
skip_char:
    inc esi
    loop process_char
    
    ; Write to output file
    mov eax, 4                     ; sys_write
    mov ebx, ecx                   ; Output file descriptor
    mov ecx, buffer                ; Buffer for writing
    mov edx, dword [bytes_read]    ; Number of bytes to write
    int 0x80
    jmp read_loop
    
close_files:
    ; Close files
    mov eax, 6                     ; sys_close
    mov ebx, ebx                   ; Close input file
    int 0x80
    mov eax, 6                     ; sys_close
    mov ebx, ecx                   ; Close output file
    int 0x80
    
exit:
    mov eax, 1                     ; sys_exit
    xor ebx, ebx                   ; Return code 0
    int 0x80
    
error_open_input:
    mov eax, 4                     ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1                     ; stdout
    mov ecx, error_open_in         ; Error message
    mov edx, len_error_open_in     ; Length of the message
    int 0x80
    jmp exit
    
error_open_output:
    mov eax, 4                     ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1                     ; stdout
    mov ecx, error_open_out        ; Error message
    mov edx, len_error_open_out    ; Length of the message
    int 0x80
    jmp exit

The program doesn't work as expected — it doesn't seem to shift characters correctly or write to the output file. What am I doing wrong? Could there be an issue with how I'm handling file descriptors or shifting the characters?
Thanks in advance for your help

You're writing your own _start, which isn't a function; there's no return address.  So unlike in main, argc is at [esp], then argv[0] at esp+4, argv[1] at esp+8, etc. i.e. the whole array is right there by value, vs. main only getting a pointer to it.

Also, you can test parts of your program separately, e.g. by jumping over or commenting out the broken input part and using mov al, 'V' or something, or putting a string in .data.    And single-step with a debugger (or even use it to jump over instructions).  Your question doesn't currently show any test results for the ASCII manipulation, so it's not a [mcve] for that part, only the argc check which your code never gets past.  (Because you're actually taking argv[0], a large integer which is a pointer.)
